# How to install redis extension for php 7

Tags: php, redis, php-7, phpredis

Referred this link https://anton.logvinenko.name/en/blog/how-to-install-redis-and-redis-php-client.html

And done following steps

PhpRedis for PHP 7 (Skip it if you have different PHP version)

Install required package

```
apt-get install php7.0-dev
```

Download PhpRedis

```
cd /tmp
wget https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/archive/php7.zip -O phpredis.zip
```

But, https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/archive/php7.zip file not found for installation.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try to use this url https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/archive/5.2.2.zip

```
wget https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/archive/5.2.2.zip -O phpredis.zip
```

Or use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install php-redis
```

Comment: with the command is it possible to specify the phpredis redis version ?

Answer (score 29):

Yesterday, I installed Redis on my Vagrant box (`/etc/php/7.0`):

- `sudo pecl install redis`
- `sudo service php7.0-fpm restart`

(optional: run `php -m` for listing the php modules).

Now, you can use the `Redis` class in your php code.

Comment: I had to do some extra work: after `sudo pecl install redis`: `echo "extension=redis.so" > /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/redis.ini && ln -sf /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/redis.ini /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-redis.ini && ln -sf /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/redis.ini /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-redis.ini`. Then `sudo service php7.0-fpm restart && sudo apache2ctl restart` was successful.

Comment: If you have PHP 7.3 with Nginx: then `sudo pecl install redis: echo "extension=redis.so" > /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/redis.ini && ln -sf /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/redis.ini /etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/20-redis.ini && ln -sf /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/redis.ini /etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-redis.ini`. Then `sudo service php7.0-fpm restart & sudo service nginx restart`

Answer (score 19):

I found a [repository][1] from ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install php-redis
```

- Restart apache after installation.
  [1]: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/php-redis

Comment: the packges not available

Comment: @famas23 https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/php-redis

Answer (score 8):

If you happen to be in a docker container just:

```
pecl install redis
docker-php-ext-enable redis
```

will do in most cases.

Comment: This actually works - I'm using php:7.3.33-apache as base for my docker image

Answer (score 6):

For people who are using MAMP, you want to execute the pecl installer from withing MAMP. This follows the installment from https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/blob/develop/INSTALL.markdown.

`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.9/bin/pecl install redis`

Change the php version to yours.

After successfully installing, will probably say something like this:

```
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "extension=redis.so" to php.ini
```

So you need to go to your php.ini, and add `extension=redis.so`.

For me, this folder is: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.9/conf/php.ini`

After restarting your MAMP, you will see a redis module on this page (ports might not be the same): `http://localhost:8888/MAMP/index.php?language=English&page=phpinfo`

Answer (score 5):

I just ran the command below for Cent os 7

```
yum install php-redis
```

Resolved my issue and i added the config in php.ini manualy

You should add "extension=redis.so" to php.ini

Answer (score 3):

For Debian-based Linux distros you need a `php-dev` and `pkg-php-tools` packages for building native PHP extension from [phpredis](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/) source code:

```sh
sudo apt update && \
    sudo apt install php-dev pkg-php-tools --yes && \
    sudo pecl channel-update pecl.php.net && \
    sudo pecl install redis
```

Answer (score 3):

Install redis with a command:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-redis
```

Answer (score 1):

[This GitHub is a great resource for MAMP users.](https://github.com/jrquick17/php-extension-library)

For Mac Users:

1. Download `redis.so` from the appropriate subdirectory of the [repo](https://github.com/jrquick17/php-extension-library)
   based on major and minor version number X.Y ([following semver](https://semver.org/)).
2. Move the file to
   `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/phpX.Y.X/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-xxxxxxxx`
3. Add `extension=redis.so` to the end of php.ini

Updated resource above, previously listed [this](https://github.com/panxianhai/php-redis-mamp)

Comment: Not working! I am using php 7.2.7 and last available is for 7.1.8

Comment: @rohitcoder Try this https://github.com/jrquick17/php-extension-library

Answer (score 0):

Me using PHP8 with Nginx an this below command work for me.

```
wget https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/archive/refs/tags/5.3.7.tar.gz
tar xf 5.3.7.tar.gz
cd phpredis-5.3.7
phpize
./configure
make
make install
echo “extension=redis.so” >> /etc/php.ini
```

To verify that phpredis was actived you can check in your php configuration like this.

```
php -i | grep redis
```

And dont remember to restart your PHP-FPM